# The Quran had 7 Qira'at, so doesn't mean it's 7 versions?

Tags: quran

I know that the Quran had 7 types of Qira'at and now the muslims use only one (I think Hafs?). So doesn't that change the interpretations and meanings of the Quran? Doesn't that mean it has 7 different versions?

I'm especially concerned since Arabic words meanings are very depended on "Tashkeel", so a change in pronunciation of a word would change its entire meaning.

[Qira'at - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qira%27at)

See especially this [Examples of Readings from Hafs and Warsh - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qira%27at#Examples_of_Readings_from_Hafs_and_Warsh)

I haven't read this, but it seems to have the answer: http://www.islamic-awareness.org/Quran/Text/Qiraat/hafs.html

Answer (score 2):

The difference in "Qira'at" are not much in a way to change the meaning of Quran! they exist just in some verses (maybe 0.01% of verses), and what is most important is that they all go in the same path.
The prophet Mohamed said: [The Quran came in 7 'letters' so read what you can of it] (my translation) not sure what you can understand by "came in 7 letters" but what we understand from the Arabic original text is that this difference in pronunciation exists, but they all go in the same meaning and change nothing from the faith or the Shari'a.
Muslim scholars say that this small differences make the meaning reaches and in some case is just a difference in pronunciation because the readers are from a different countries. (Muslims of Iraq and Syria and Saudi Arabia have different pronunciation of the same words in Arabic)
It is just like British English and American English! when you say 'color' or 'colour' you say it in a different way but still the same meaning! or when you say 'drink-driving' in BE and "drunk driving" in AE, or "maths" in BE and "math" in AE.

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Your answer is not convincing. Have you seen the examples from the wiki page? "Hafs: you do", "Warsh: they do". "He said", "say". Those are *huge* differences, not just a pronunciation difference as in BE and AE. This is a meaning difference.

Comment: @JackTwain There are meaning differences, but the meaning differences don't make a difference! Essentially all of them are co-valid and non-contradictory. For example, the one you mentioned is: "Allah is not unaware of what [you do/they do]." Both are true, and neither contradicts the other!

Answer (score -2):

No. All the Qurans in the world are the same, its something critical, all copies had to be the same even the pronunciation have to be the same, because in Arabic language "tashkeel" is something important, you can change the whole meaning just only by one "tashkel".

You can read it in any language you find it easy to you to get the right meaning and the concept of it, the most important thing that our god knows everything in your heart so be clean from inside and you will get what you want, a lot of Arab readers read in their way, but for Arab its clear that if this reader is right or not, so because of your not Arab its hard to manage and get the idea.

Comment: you didn't answer the question. You just defended your point of view.

Comment: it was clear before the editor edit my answer ;)