# What proof do we have that the Quran we are using is the right version?

Tags: quran, authenticity

We are aware that the Quran we are using today is the version compiled by Uthman RA. Uthman RA ordered the burning of all other versions of the Quran. What proof do we have that the Quran we are using is the right version?

Comment: Are you mixing up Qur'an and Mus-haf? The mus-hafs we have today are based on the 'Uthmanic compilation, but the Qur'an is through memorization and ijazah all the way to the Prophet, not through codices.

Comment: I am not very well knowledgeable about whether it is Quran and mus-hafs, if  you can formulate your comment as a answer and explains a bit more, that will help,

Comment: @III-AK-III, I don't understand this part in your comment , "Qur'an is through memorization and ijazah", the  mus-hafs that we have, does it not contain the Quran ? Why differenciating between  mus-hafs and Quran ?

Comment: Noor, This [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40078/15201) (with no answer atm) seems to be related

Comment: perhaps we can use seerah of prophet Yusuf compare to Joseph in old testament or Musa (when he met Syuaib) to Moses (met Jethro). That way we can know for sure it tells the truth

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul, i don't understand your comment and is unable to make a liaison with my question

Comment: What is really new in this post, which is not covered in posts such as https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/is-the-quran-really-preserved-or-are-there-missing-parts-of-the-quran, https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2676/what-are-the-readings-qiraat-of-quran, https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30508/different-versions-of-arabic-quran and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33343/read-quran-with-tafseer-alone

Comment: @Noor the seerah of those prophet can be used to compare the story from people of the Injil and AlQuran. Please check Ali Imran: 3